# get list of mailbox c# ae.net.mail

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to get the list of the folders under the INBOX.I try the foloowing:but I dont know what I need to send where below there are ??

```
bool headersOnly = false;
ic.SelectMailbox("INBOX");
Lazy<MailMessage>[] messages = ic.SearchMessages(SearchCondition.Unseen(), headersOnly);
foreach (Lazy<MailMessage> message in messages)
{
   AE.Net.Mail.Imap.Mailbox[] m2 = ic.ListMailboxes**("??","??");**
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly the next time...

Comment: bash.d can you hekp me here?

Comment: No, sorry, I would have, if I could.

Answer (score 2):

I've used the following code to get all emails from my Gmail account and it works fine.

```
AE.Net.Mail.ImapClient client = new AE.Net.Mail.ImapClient(emailHost, emailAddress, emailPassword, AE.Net.Mail.AuthMethods.Login, port, useSsl);
AE.Net.Mail.Imap.Mailbox[] mailBoxes = client.ListMailboxes(string.Empty, "*");
foreach (var mailBox in mailBoxes)
{
    var mailboxName = mailBox.Name;
}
```